# C++ program stuck in an infinite loop

Tags: c++, loops

Please note that I am a complete beginner at C++. I'm trying to write a simple program for an ATM and I have to account for all errors. User may use only integers for input so I need to check if input value is indeed an integer, and my program (this one is shortened) works for the most part.

The problem arises when I try to input a string value instead of an integer while choosing an operation. It works with invalid value integers, but with strings it creates an infinite loop until it eventually stops (unless I add `system("cls")`, then it doesn't even stop), when it should output the same result as it does for invalid integers:

```
Invalid choice of operation.
Please select an operation:

 1 - Balance inquiry
 7 - Return card

Enter your choice and press return:
```

Here is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;


bool isNumber(string s) //function to determine if input value is int
{
    for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++)
        if (isdigit(s[i]) == false)
            return false;
    return true;
}


int ReturnCard() //function to determine whether to continue running or end program
{
    string rtrn;

    cout << "\nDo you wish to continue? \n1 - Yes \n2 - No, return card" << endl;
    cin >> rtrn;
    if (rtrn == "1" and isNumber(rtrn)) { return false; }
    else if (rtrn == "2" and isNumber(rtrn)) { return true; }
    else {cout << "Invalid choice." << endl; ReturnCard(); };
    return 0;
}


int menu() //function for operation choice and execution
{
    int choice;
    do
    {
        cout << "\nPlease select an operation:\n" << endl
            << " 1 - Balance inquiry\n"
            << " 7 - Return card\n"
            << "\nEnter your choice and press return: ";
        int balance = 512;
        cin >> choice;
        if (choice == 1 and isNumber(to_string(choice))) { cout << "Your balance is $" << balance; "\n\n"; }
        else if (choice == 7 and isNumber(to_string(choice))) { cout << "Please wait...\nHave a good day." << endl; return 0; }
        else { cout << "Invalid choice of operation.";  menu(); }
    } while (ReturnCard()==false);
    cout << "Please wait...\nHave a good day." << endl;
    return 0;
}

int main()
{
    string choice;
    cout << "Insert debit card to get started." << endl;
    menu();
    return 0;
}
```

I've tried every possible solution I know, but nothing seems to work.

***There is a different bug, which is that when I get to the "Do you wish to continue?" part and input any invalid value and follow it up with 2 (which is supposed to end the program) after it asks again, it outputs the result for 1 (continue running - menu etc.). I have already emailed my teacher about this and this is not my main question, but I would appreciate any help.

Thank you!

Comment: `isNumber` seems superfluous, you call it with `"1"` or `"2"`.

Comment: What is the content of the string? You can print that with `cout << rtrn;`

Comment: You miss a `return ReturnCard();` for your recursive call.

Comment: The type of `choice` is `int`. It is never anything except an integer, so there is no point in checking. There are essentially two ways of determining that input is an integer: 1) Reading it succeeds (`if (cin >> choice) ...`); and 2) Reading a string and succesfully converting it to an integer.

Comment: Under what conditions do you expect `isNumber(to_string(choice))` to be false? You have already determined that `choice` is either 1 or 7, and those are probably numbers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are a few things mixed up in your code. Always try to compile your code with maximum warnings turned on, e.g., for GCC add at least the `-Wall` flag.
Then your compiler would warn you of some of the mistakes you made.

First, it seems like you are confusing `string choice` and `int choice`. Two different variables in different scopes. The `string` one is **unused** and completely redundant. You can delete it and nothing will change.

In menu, you say `cin >> choice;`, where `choice` is of type `int`. The stream operator `>>` works like this: It will try to read as many characters as it can, such that the characters match the requested *type*. So this will **only** read ints.

Then you convert your valid `int` into a string and call `isNumber()` - which will **alway** return true.

So if you wish to read any line of text and handle it, you can use [`getline()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline):

```
string inp;
std::getline(std::cin, inp);
if (!isNumber(inp)) {
    std::cout << "ERROR\n";
    return 1;
}

int choice = std::stoi(inp); // May throw an exception if invalid range
```

See [stoi](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/stol)

Your `isNumber()` implementation could look like this:

```
#include <algorithm>

bool is_number(const string &inp) {
  return std::all_of(inp.cbegin(), inp.cend(), 
    [](unsigned char c){ return std::isdigit(c); });
}
```

If you are into that functional style, like I am ;)

**EDIT:**

Btw., another bug which the compiler warns about: `cout << "Your balance is $" << balance; "\n\n";` - the newlines are separated by `;`, so it's a new statement and this does nothing. You probably wanted the `<<` operator instead.

**Recursive call bug:**

In `{ cout << "Invalid choice of operation.";  menu(); }` and same for `ReturnCard()`, the function calls itself (recursion).
This is not at all what you want! This will start the function over, but once *that* call has ended, you continue where that call happened.
What you want in `menu()` is to **start the loop over**. You can do that with the `continue` keyword.
You want the same for `ReturnCard()`. But you need a loop there.
And now, that I read that code, you don't even need to convert the input to an integer. All you do is compare it. So you can simply do:

```
string inp;
std::getline(std::cin, inp);
if (inp == "1" || inp == "2") {
  // good
} else {
  // Invalid
}
```

Unless that is part of your task.

Answer (score 1):

It is always good to save console input in a string variable instead of another
type, e.g. `int` or `double`. This avoids trouble with input errors, e.g. if
characters instead of numbers are given by the program user. Afterwards the
string variable could by analyzed for further actions.
Therefore I changed the type of `choice` from `int` to `string` and adopted the
downstream code to it.

Please try the following program and consider my adaptations which are
written as comments starting with tag `//CKE:`. Thanks.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;


bool isNumber(const string& s) //function to determine if input value is int
{
    for (size_t i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) //CKE: keep same variable type, e.g. unsigned
        if (isdigit(s[i]) == false)
            return false;
    return true;
}


bool ReturnCard() //function to determine whether to continue running or end program
{
    string rtrn;

    cout << "\nDo you wish to continue? \n1 - Yes \n2 - No, return card" << endl;
    cin >> rtrn;
    if (rtrn == "1" and isNumber(rtrn)) { return false; }
    if (rtrn == "2" and isNumber(rtrn)) { return true; } //CKE: remove redundant else
    cout << "Invalid choice." << endl; ReturnCard(); //CKE: remove redundant else + semicolon
    return false;
}


int menu() //function for operation choice and execution
{
    string choice; //CKE: change variable type here from int to string
    do
    {
        cout << "\nPlease select an operation:\n" << endl
            << " 1 - Balance inquiry\n"
            << " 7 - Return card\n"
            << "\nEnter your choice and press return: ";
        int balance = 512;
        cin >> choice;
        if (choice == "1" and isNumber(choice)) { cout << "Your balance is $" << balance << "\n\n"; } //CKE: semicolon replaced by output stream operator
        else if (choice == "7" and isNumber(choice)) { cout << "Please wait...\nHave a good day." << endl; return 0; }
        else { cout << "Invalid choice of operation."; } //CKE: remove recursion here as it isn't required
    } while (!ReturnCard()); //CKE: negate result of ReturnCard function
    cout << "Please wait...\nHave a good day." << endl;
    return 0;
}

int main()
{
    string choice;
    cout << "Insert debit card to get started." << endl;
    menu();
    return 0;
}
```